# Trying to read a weird XML file

Tags: php, xml

Okay, so basically, i'm trying to make a game library from a save file using PHP. Extracting the XML datas provide me with a weird XML file that has 2 <?xml> declaration and i don't know the most efficient way to deal with it.
Is there a special type of file that can read both or something other than simplexml_load_file to read it successfully ? Or maybe i could read the file first and separate it in 2 differents xml files (i wouldn't know how atm but i'd work on it)

If anyone know how to deal with it tho i'd love some help !

Haven't tried much rn, just basic xml outputs with manual extraction of both xml declarations but i'd like to automate it.

Comment: I don't think an XML file should ever have two `<?xml>` declarations. This sounds like a problem with whatever creates the file, and you should fix that.

Comment: You could read the file into a string, remove everything starting from the second `<?xml>` (or everything before the last `<?xml>`, depending on which one contains the data you want), then use `simplexml_load_string()`

Answer (score -2):

You could load the file in and you [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to parse the file and its commands, ultimately it depends on what you want to do with the data in the file and what the data represents.